# c++ custom container pass {} list

Tags: c++, c++11

I am basically remaking the set container and I am wondering how I pass a brace-enclosed initializer list to the container.

```
mySet<int> myset = {"test", "test 2"};
```

I tried to overload the operator= to take a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the presence of the `=` here, this is constructing a set, so what you need is a constructor (that takes an `std::initializer_list` as its parameter).

```
template<class T>
class myset { 
public:
// ...
    mySet(std::initializer_list<T> init) {
        for (T const &t : init)
            insert(t);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a constructor which take a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as its parameter, such as:

```
template <class T>
class mySet {
public:
    mySet(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a constructor that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as a parameter, like

```
mySet(std::initializer_list<T> args){/*...*/}
```

`operator=` is invoked only on assignments, not on [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (your case). In this latter case the constructor is invoked on the rhs, followed by a copy (or move), which is usually elided, but nevertheless the copy or move ctors must be accessible.